# Nested $rootScope.$digest() in AngularJS unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a promise that needs to be resolved before I can call another method. This other method does not return a promise, but it does use a promise. I need to check that this final promise is resolved and the data is set correctly. To do this, I need to call root$scope.$digest(), but if I call it inside a promise, there is already a $rootScope.$digest() loop in progress outside the promise and I get an error. Code:

```
 //spec file
 var promise = doSomething();
 promise.then(function(data) {
      expect(data).toEqual(stub);
      callSomeOtherMethod();//this method has a promise that needs to be resolved
      $rootScope.$digest();//cannot do this
 });
 $rootScope.$digest();//if I remove this, promise is not resolved
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

EDIT:

I can add a second $rootScope.$digest() outside the promise and that will allow the someOtherMethod() promise to be evaluated, but it still throws off synchronicity because any expects inside the code will be checked against pre-promise values.

Comment: have you tried calling `$rootScope.$digest()` twice, outside of the promise callback?

Comment: This does not seem to work, unfortunately. No error but the final promise is not evaluated. EDIT: It does work, but you need to remove any done() jasmine async invocations. Thanks!